# Do AWS IAM policies need to be "reciprocal" for API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-policies

Do policies need to be defined on both sides of a relationship?

For example, suppose I have a Lambda with a policy that allows every principal on the account to invoke it. If I create an API Gateway that needs to invoke that Lambda, do I need to create a policy that gives the API GW explicit permission to do it? Or the Lambda's policy inherently allows the API Gateway to invoke it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes, permissions are required on both ends.

However, in this scenario, only the lambda's policy (which is a "resource based policy") is needed for the API gateway to be able to invoke the lambda.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html):

> Amazon API Gateway gets permission to invoke your function from the function's resource-based policy. You can grant invoke permission to an entire API, or grant limited access to a stage, resource, or method.